# Laravel Homestead Windows Not Mapping Folders Properties

Tags: windows, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm unable to map my local project directory to Laravel's Homestead project directory. Inside of my homestead.yaml file I have:

```
folders:
    - map: C:\Users\mdgre\Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

When I run `vagrant up` I see the incorrect mapping taking place:

```
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/mdgre/.homestead
```

In addition when I `ssh` into the vagrant box no Code folder has been created at `home/vagrant/Code`.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of homestead are you running?  As of 5.0.0 there is no more `~/.homestead` directory and shared folders are mounted using the `Homestead.yaml` config in the same directory as the `Vagrantfile`.

Comment: I'm running 4.0.5. Perhaps this is the issue. I can try when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in the VirtualBox 5.1.16 version. You can update to the 5.1.18 version. It works in this version